# Multi step form validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am new to jQuery and I have no idea on how to implement some jQuery validation on a jQuery form I downloaded.

I am using this form: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/jquery-multi-step-form-with-progress-bar

Server side validation is already done in php but I need jQuery so that the users cannot click on the Next button if they haven't wronte anything on those fields.(same behavious as the required html attribute for input tags)

I've tried all sorts of things by copying and pasting jQuery validation code from other people but without any success. So if anyone could help me out on this issue I would really appreciate it (will buy you a penguin as I am a linux admin =p )

Kind regards,
Ciprian

Comment: Please show us some code of what you already have. Then we know what you already tried. You can post the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: So you already copy and paste from others and have problems finding clue what you're doing, so then you need to ask others to help you even with copy and paste. Yeah. Right. Welcome to Stackoverflow, the great plains of copy and paste Q&A.

Comment: @Raffael: Thank you for the suggestion and for responding. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ANWXy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll want to include a Validation Plugin. [Here's](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) a really good one.

Then you'll want to add the `required` tag to all inputs required.

Then when the user clicks the 'Next' buttons, you'll want to validate the form like so.

```
$('#msform').validate();
if (!$('#msform').valid()) {
    return false;
}
```

Place the above code right after `$(".next").click(function(){` and you'll be set.

I've built a working copy of this code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/sgNH4/2/). The inputs on the first slide are required. Then on the next slide, the first input is required.

Please note that this project requires **three** JavaScript files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://thecodeplayer.com/uploads/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hello Graham, thank you your code works like a charm.